# Full Text Search in Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, search, full-text-search

There's no full text search built into Linq and there don't seem to be many posts on the subject so I had a play around and came up with this method for my utlity class:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> GenericFullTextSearch<TSource>(string text, MyDataContext context)
{
    //Find LINQ Table attribute
    object[] info = typeof(TSource).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute), true);
    //Get table name
    String table = (info[0] as System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute).Name;
    //Full text search on that table
    return context.ExecuteQuery<TSource>(String.Concat("SELECT * FROM ", table, " WHERE CONTAINS(*, {0})"), text);
}
```

And added this wrapper to each partial Linq class where there is a full text index

```
public static IEnumerable<Pet> FullTextSearch(string text, MyDataContext context)
{
    return (LinqUtilities.GenericFullTextSearch<Pet>(text, context) as IEnumerable<Pet>);
}
```

So now I can do full text searches with neat stuff like

```
var Pets = Pet.FullTextSearch(helloimatextbox.Text, MyDataContext).Skip(10).Take(10);
```

I'm assuming only a very basic search is necessary at present. Can anyone improve on this? Is it possible to implement as an extension method and avoid the wrapper?

Comment: One dangerous/unoptimal issue regarding your query is that the .Skip().Take() will be performed clientside, not serverside. So if you do a FTS that returns 10^6 results and you want to just have the first 10, all 10^6 of them will be returned from the database, and only then will you perform the filtering.

Comment: Aye, on a dataset that big I would be considering another technique ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use Full Text Search (FTS) with LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224475/is-it-possible-to-use-full-text-search-fts-with-linq)

Answer (score 9):

The neatest solution is to use an inline table valued function in sql and add it to your model

http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2008/12/18/LINQ-to-SQL---Enabling-Fulltext-searching.aspx

> To get it working you need to create a table valued function that does
> nothing more than a `CONTAINSTABLE` query based on the keywords you
> pass in,
>
> ```sql
> create function udf_sessionSearch
>       (@keywords nvarchar(4000)) returns table as   return (select [SessionId],[rank]
>             from containstable(Session,(description,title),@keywords))
> ```
>
> You then add this function to your LINQ 2 SQL model and he presto you
> can now write queries like.
>
> ```cs
> var sessList = from s   in DB.Sessions
>                join fts in DB.udf_sessionSearch(SearchText) on s.sessionId equals fts.SessionId
>                select s;
> ```

Comment: This also requires a udf per table from what I can see, the OPs solution should work with all tables.  Thanks for the post though

Answer (score 4):

I was pretty frustrated with the lack of clear examples... especially when there are potentially large data sets and paging is needed. So, here's an example that hopefully encompasses everything you might need :-)

```
create function TS_projectResourceSearch
    (   @KeyStr nvarchar(4000), 
        @OwnId int,
        @SkipN int,
        @TakeN int )
    returns @srch_rslt table (ProjectResourceId bigint not null, Ranking int not null )
    as 
    begin

        declare @TakeLast int
        set @TakeLast = @SkipN + @TakeN
        set @SkipN = @SkipN + 1

        insert into @srch_rslt  
        select pr.ProjectResourceId, Ranking
        from 
        (
            select t.[KEY] as ProjectResourceId, t.[RANK] as Ranking, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by t.[Rank] desc) row_num
            from containstable( ProjectResource,(ResourceInfo, ResourceName), @KeyStr )
            as t        
        ) as r
        join ProjectResource pr on r.ProjectResourceId = pr.ProjectResourceId
        where (pr.CreatorPersonId = @OwnId
            or pr.ResourceAvailType < 40)
            and r.row_num between @SkipN and @TakeLast
        order by r.Ranking desc 

        return
    end
    go


    select * from ts_projectResourceSearch(' "test*" ',1002, 0,1)
```

Enjoy,
Patrick

Answer (score 4):

I use a little hack using [Provider Wrapper](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32) techniques. I have a c# code that rewrite magic word in SQL with FTS search for MS SQL (you can adjust for any server you like).

if you have context class MyEntities, create subclass like

```
public class MyEntitiesWithWrappers : MyEntities
{
    private IEFTraceListener listener;
    public string FullTextPrefix = "-FTSPREFIX-";

    public MyEntitiesWithWrappers(): this("name=MyEntities")
    {
    }

    public MyEntitiesWithWrappers(string connectionString)
        : base(EntityConnectionWrapperUtils.CreateEntityConnectionWithWrappers(connectionString,"EFTracingProvider"))
    {
        TracingConnection.CommandExecuting += RewriteFullTextQuery;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rewrites query that contains predefined prefix like: where n.NOTETEXT.Contains(Db.FullTextPrefix  + text) with SQL server FTS 
    /// To be removed when EF will support FTS
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="o"></param>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    public void RewriteFullTextQuery(object o, CommandExecutionEventArgs args)
    {
        var text = args.Command.CommandText;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Command.Parameters.Count; i++)
        {
            DbParameter parameter = args.Command.Parameters[i];
            if (parameter.DbType.In(DbType.String, DbType.AnsiString, DbType.StringFixedLength, DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength))
            {
                if (parameter.Value == DBNull.Value)
                    continue;
                var value = (string) parameter.Value;
                parameter.Size = 4096;
                if (value.IndexOf(FullTextPrefix) >= 0)
                {
                    value = value.Replace(FullTextPrefix, ""); // remove prefix we added n linq query
                    value = value.Substring(1, value.Length-2); // remove %% escaping by linq translator from string.Contains to sql LIKE
                    parameter.Value = value;
                    args.Command.CommandText = Regex.Replace(text,
                        string.Format(@"\(\[(\w*)\].\[(\w*)\]\s*LIKE\s*@{0}\s?(?:ESCAPE '~')\)", parameter.ParameterName), 
                        string.Format(@"contains([$1].[$2], @{0})", parameter.ParameterName));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var fullTextSearch = Db.FullTextPrefix + textToSearch;
var q = Db.Notes.Where(n => !n.Private && n.NoteText.Contains(fullTextSearch));
```

Answer (score 3):

A slighty nicer method (takes rank into effect) using CONTAINSTABLE

```
String pkey = context.Mapping.GetTable(typeof(TSource)).RowType.DataMembers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsPrimaryKey).Name;
string query = String.Concat(@"SELECT *
    FROM ", table, @" AS FT_TBL INNER JOIN
    CONTAINSTABLE(", table, @", *, {0}) AS KEY_TBL
    ON FT_TBL.", pkey, @" = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
    ORDER BY KEY_TBL.[RANK] DESC");
return context.ExecuteQuery<TSource>(query, text);
```

Answer (score 2):

.NET Core 2.1 and above supports an extension method that allows the use of `FREETEXT` and `FREETEXTTABLE` searches

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var results = dbContext.MyTable
        .Where(e => EF.Functions.FreeText("*", "search criteria"));
```

The `FreeText` function is defined in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` so your project must reference that package.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.freetext)

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to solve the exact problem. I like to write my SQL logic in my LINQtoSQL but I needed a way to do Full Text Search. right now I'm just using SQL functions and then calling the user-defined functions inline of the linq queries. not sure if that's the most efficient way. what do you guys think?

Answer (score -3):

You can just do something like this

```
    var results = (from tags in _dataContext.View_GetDeterminationTags
                   where tags.TagName.Contains(TagName) ||
                   SqlMethods.Like(tags.TagName,TagName)
                   select new DeterminationTags
                   {
                       Row = tags.Row,
                       Record = tags.Record,
                       TagID = tags.TagID,
                       TagName = tags.TagName,
                       DateTagged = tags.DateTagged,
                       DeterminationID = tags.DeterminationID,
                       DeterminationMemberID = tags.DeterminationMemberID,
                       MemberID = tags.MemberID,
                       TotalTagged = tags.TotalTagged.Value
                   }).ToList();
```

Notice where TagName.Contains also the SQLMethods.Like just do a using

```
using System.Data.Linq.SqlClient;
```

to gain access to that SQLMethods.

Comment: That .contains translates into a LIKE '%TAGNAME%', which is suboptimal.

Comment: `LIKE` is not a `FULLTEXT` search.

Answer (score -4):

dswatik - the reason for wanting full text search is that .contains translates to

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE COLUMNNAME LIKE '%TEXT%'
```

Which ignores any indexes and is horrible on a large table.