# How do I build up LINQ dynamically

Tags: linq, dynamic, operators

I have a scenario where I have custom configured column names, associated operators like < > = between etc. and then a value associated.

I'm trying to determine if it is possible to build up a LINQ query with a dynamic (string) where clause?

I've noticed the Predicate.OR Preditcate.AND stuff, but that is not quite what I'm talking about.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736952/the-best-way-to-build-dynamic-linq-query question

Comment: " However Dynamic linq only works on IQueryable and not IEnumerable" - see the note about AsQueryable on my reply...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are talking about a *string* `Where` clause (rather than building the expression etc yourself) - then the [Dynamic LINQ Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) (in the 3.5 samples, IIRC) should suffice.

Note that the example below is for database usage; but you can use it with LINQ-to-Objects by calling `.AsQueryable()` on your in-memory data.

[image]

Comment: Although Alex was first with the Dynamic LINQ library, the part that was missing was raised by Marc (sorry for missing that).  You need the .AsQueryAble() extension method to be able to work with your collections.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, there is a specific library from Microsoft (**System.Linq.Dynamic**) that comes with the C# VS2008 samples that supports this. Get it from [here (Microsoft Download)](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx)

The library is included in the \LinqSamples\DynamicQuery directory of the samples of above download.

For extensive usage examples check this page: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: Ok, System.Linq.Dynamic looks like exactly what I'm looking for at first glance.

However Dynamic linq only works on IQueryable and not IEnumerable.

So this still leaves a bit of a problem.

Comment: @Jabezz That's not a problem, It should only work on `IQueryable` because of the design and the intention of `IQueryable`. (Read [This article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/ienumerable-vs-iqueryable-in-linq) to better understand how IQueryable returns data on-demand.) There is a `IEnumerable.AsQueryable` extension method which allows you to get an IQueryable based on your IEnumerable.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use expression trees to created dynamic queries. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2005/09/30/expressiontrees

http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx

Comment: That's a safer way than to use DynamicLinq, which seems very injection-vulnerable.