# How can I use dynamic LINQ in my asp.net project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq, dynamic-linq

How can I use dynamic LINQ in Visual Studio 2008?

I'm trying to use

```
using System.linq.Dynamic
```

but there is no intellisense. How can I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find the answer in here:

[How do I build up LINQ dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292482/how-do-i-build-up-linq-dynamically)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'll first say that dynamic LINQ is *usually* overkill, but sometimes useful. But you should just be able to reference the dll and away you go. If no intellisense is appearing, but it *compiles*, then check where (physically) the dynamic linq dll is located. Ensure the "foo.dll.xml" file is located next to "foo.dll" (where "foo" is the assembly - perhaps `System.Linq.Dynamic` ?). This is key for intellisense when using assembly references.

Comment: How can download Dynamic linq? try to add refrence there isn't

Comment: @Phsika - it is in the samples - here, IIRC: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/cs2008samples

Comment: @Phsika - alternative link: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx

Comment: And of course, the Gu: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with this and this is how I got it work:

1. Place the Dynamic.cs file in the App_Code folder of your application (not sure this is absolutely necessary but I'd it anyway)
2. **Once there right click this file (Dynamic.cs) in your solution explorer and in it's properties window change the build action to COMPILE! (this is crucial)**
3. Now you need to add using System.Linq.Dynamic; where you intend to use it

[thanks to this guy](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/linqprojectgeneral/thread/8512e7b2-a4bf-4c9c-9353-5b9d2c3107b4)