# How to use full-text search with Linq?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are 4 functions provided in SQL Server 2008 for full-text search:
CONTAINS, CONTAINSTABLE, FREETEXT, FREETEXTTABLE

How to use it them with Linq ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot translate a linq query into full-text search functions, there is no direct support for this.

However, there are some workarounds - see http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2008/12/18/LINQ-to-SQL---Enabling-Fulltext-searching.aspx for an indirect method of using full-text search.

Answer (score 1):

See stackoverflow post "[Is it possible to use Full Text Search (FTS) with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224475/is-it-possible-to-use-full-text-search-fts-with-linq)" which provides a link to the blog post "[Linq to SQL - Enabling Fulltext Search](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2008/12/18/LINQ-to-SQL---Enabling-Fulltext-searching.aspx)"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no built-in support for those functions in LINQ - you'll need to formulate your T-SQL query and then use the Linq's `DataContext.ExecuteQuery()` call to send that T-SQL directly to SQL Server.