# Linq to SQL Search Query

Tags: linq-to-sql, search, full-text-search, search-engine

I have a table of news, and I want to allow the user to search in it. Something like this:

```
News.Where(p => p.Title == user_query);
```

...that will allow more advanced queries, like `Differences Between "Linq to Objects" and "Linq to SQL" queries`, etc. Also it should be case-insensitive.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224475/is-it-possible-to-use-full-text-search-fts-with-linq

Answer (score 0):

From [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33/john)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224475/is-it-possible-to-use-full-text-search-fts-with-linq/385808#385808):

LINQ to SQL does not support Full Text Search, but you can write a stored procedure and call that. See [this blog post](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2008/12/18/LINQ-to-SQL---Enabling-Fulltext-searching.aspx) for more details.