# How i use Contains for string in Linq to Sql to match only the beginning of a word

Tags: linq-to-sql, contains

I can use linq to sql to match a part of a string with

```
From C In DB.City Where C.Name.Contains(Query)
```

What i need to do for it to match only beginning of words? (Behave like full text index)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if the first word starts with the query by using [`StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx) instead of `Contains`:

```
C.Name.StartsWith(Query)
```

This only checks the first word, not all words in the string.

You can't do a full text search directly using LINQ. What you can do instead is create a stored procedure to do the full text search and call that using LINQ.

**Related question**:

- [Is it possible to use Full Text Search (FTS) with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224475/is-it-possible-to-use-full-text-search-fts-with-linq)

**See also:**

- [LINQ to SQL - Enabling Fulltext searching](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2008/12/18/LINQ-to-SQL---Enabling-Fulltext-searching.aspx)