# Importing SQL Server's CONTAINS() as a model defined function

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, full-text-search

I am trying to import SQL Server's CONTAINS() function in my Entity Framework model so that I can use it in my LINQ queries.

I have added this to my EDM:

```
<Function Name="FullTextSearch" ReturnType="Edm.Boolean">
    <Parameter Name="Filter" Type="Edm.String" />
    <DefiningExpression>
        CONTAINS(*, Filter)
    </DefiningExpression>
</Function>
```

Add created my method stub:

```
[EdmFunction("MyModelNamespace", "FullTextSearch")]
public static bool FullTextSearch(string filter)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("This function is only for L2E query.");
}
```

I try to call the function like this:

```
from product in Products
where MyModel.FullTextSearch("FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, robe)")
select product
```

The following exception is raised:

```
The query syntax is not valid. Near term '*'
```

I realize that the function I defined is not directly linked to the entity set being queried so that could also be a problem.

Is there any way to pull this off?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224475/is-it-possible-to-use-full-text-search-fts-with-linq

Comment: The suggested solution in this question is to import a table-valued function, which works for LINQ to SQL but not (currenty) for Entity Framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you have defined above uses Entity SQL, not Transact SQL, so I think the first step is to figure out whether CONTAINS(*,'text') can be expressed in Entity SQL.

Entity SQL doesn't support the * operator as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738573.aspx and if I try

```
entities.CreateQuery<TABLE_NAME>("select value t from TABLE_NAME as t where CONTAINS(*, 'text')");
```

I get the same error you got above. If I try to explicitly pass the column it works:

```
entities.CreateQuery<TABLE_NAME>("select value t from TABLE_NAME as t where CONTAINS(t.COLUMN_NAME, 'text')");
```

But when I look at the SQL it translated it to a LIKE expression.

```
ADO.NET:Execute Reader "SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[TABLE_NAME] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[COLUMN_NAME] LIKE '%text%') THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT ([Extent1].[COLUMN_NAME] LIKE '%text%')) THEN cast(0 as bit) END) = 1
)  AS [GroupBy1]"
```

If you cannot express the query using Entity SQL you'll have to use a Stored Procedure or other mechanism to use Transact SQL directly.

Answer (score 1):

This is way beyond me but could you try

```
from product in Products where MyModel.FullTextSearch(product, "FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, robe)") select product
```

My reasoning is that in SQL Server it is expecting two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I inserted a little function into my code, in a class which inherits from the Context class, which points to my SQL function supporting Full Text searching, my solution is a little more closed ended to yours (not allowing the specification of the type of text search), it returns an IEnumerable, essentially a list of primary keys matching the searching criteria, something like this;

```
public class myContext : DataContext
{

     protected class series_identity
     {
            public int seriesID;

            series_identity() { }
     };

            [Function(Name = "dbo.fnSeriesFreeTextSearchInflectional", IsComposable = true)]
            protected IQueryable<series_identity> SynopsisSearch([Parameter(DbType = "NVarChar")] string value)
            {
                return this.CreateMethodCallQuery<series_identity>(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), value);
            }

            public IEnumerable<int> Search(string value)
            {
                var a = from t1 in SynopsisSearch(value)
                        select t1.seriesID;

                return a;
            }
};
```

usage is something like;

```
myContext context = new myContext();

IEnumerable<int> series_identities = (from t1 in context.Search("some term")
                                                  select t1).Distinct();
```